# GIT: adding file adds to all branches

Tags: git, branch

I'm new to Git.

i created a branch off of master.  I'm working in that branch. i then go and create a new file in that new branch. I then switch back to master to view something.

i see that file that i just added when i switch over to master as a file to add? I don't want to add that file to the master branch. Aren't those branches supposed to be completely independent of each other? I added it to the new branch, not the master branch.  How can i separate the branches?

Comment: Besides Thilo's (correct) answer, it's worth keeping in mind the three "parts" (I'm not sure what term to use here) there are for the things you work on when making commits: there are the *commits* inside the repository, but there is the *index (also called the *staging area* or sometimes the *cache*), and the *work-tree*, where you can view and edit the file. A file in the work-tree is merely in the work-tree. A file `git add`ed is in the work-tree *and* in the index. The index *becomes* the next commit when you `git commit`, but until then, the file is just floating there in the index.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you `git add` a file, but then switch branches before committing, the staged addition will be carried over to the new branch (just like any other staged changes). You probably wanted to `commit` before switching branches.

Any uncommitted changes, including files that are not added to the repository, are preserved when switching the working copy between branches.

Just making a new file does not automatically add it to the repository, you have to do a `git add myFile` (and eventually `commit` that).

Or, looking at it the other way, even if the file stays around in your working copy when you switch branches, it won't become part of those other branches unless you explicitly add and commit them there, either.

Comment: actually i hadn't done an git add either, i had just created the file and added it to the folder.  but sounds like the best thing to do is stash the changes, to avoid this issue. just need to make sure that is done before switching. file changes too would get confusing cause i wouldn't know what files were changed for which branch.